# Brown tips of peace lily?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, container-gardening, peace-lily

I have 3 palants of peace lily, [image: image of plants]

Placed more or less 6 feets away form windows(2windows), [image: location of plants]
,
I never over water them, I wait for my plants to give me signs of thirst(wilt a little bit),each pot has several drainage holes..
Also the soil is very vell drained..
.in addition I use water from a tubewell, means no chloride, no chlorine,  no fluoride, 
Nither I have ever used any fertilizer since I brought the home..
Humidity levels are also doing fine at 60%[image: humidity 64%]. ..
But still their tips are getting brown, [image: leafs of every plant is tunnig brown]
[image: same problem *browning leaf on each plant]..
Can some one please tell me, what mistake I am making? 
Please help this black thumb,

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption you're watering correctly, that is, watering copiously, then tipping out any excess water from the outer pot or tray after 30 minutes, if you're in the States, it might be the tap water, so try using bottled water instead. If you're allowing them to sit in water or not watering sufficiently well when you do water, correct that. Alternatively, dry air/low humidity can cause this problem - Peace Lily appreciates being misted with water 2 or 3 times a week. Other causes could be excessive use of fertilizer, but you haven't mentioned this at all.

Comment: each pot has several drainage hole..
Also the soil is very vell drained..
.in addition I use water from a tubewell, means no chloride, no chlorine,  no fluoride

Comment: Humidity level 60 %, no fertilizer has been used since I bought them home,